# Extracting JSON from JSON String Android

Tags: android, json

In Android, I have been trying to extract the string '`FavoriteColors`' , '`Green`'  and '`1234`' and also put the key's into a String array `RecordId,Data,user`.

```
[RecordId={S: FavoriteColors,}, Data={S: Green,}, user id={S: 1234,}]'
```

The String keys are the column names of my Database and the values are the entries.

Comment: This string is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I'm using DynamoDb to get all items form DB (item.entrySet().toString()) When i log this. that is the string produced. Is there another way to read from Dynamo?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon DynamoDB uses JavaScript Object Notation format (JSON) to send and receive formatted data. JSON presents data in a hierarchy so that both data values and data structure are conveyed simultaneously. Name-value pairs are defined in the format name:value. The data hierarchy is defined by nested brackets of name-value pairs.

You may read office doc [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataFormat.html).

Comment: Glad to help, if you feel i was help you, you can up vote my answer, thx

Comment: I would but I need more rep :) ill give you a + 2